# Laravel 5 instantiate model with where clause

Tags: php, laravel-5

In my controller, I want to be able to call the model Category and give it an array ('dbField' => 'value') and I want to be able to use this array in a where clause.

My Controller:

```
$categories = new Category(['name' => 'category name']);
```

My Model:

```
public function __construct($attributes = [])
{
  parent::__construct($attributes);
...
}
```

But it doesn't seem to work that way, whenever you pass attributes to the model constructor it's only for mass assignement, is there any way to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constructor is for filling attributes.

You can try an actual where

```
$attributes = ['name' => 'blah'];

$findIt = Category::where($attributes)->get(); // or first();

// get the first matched record based on the attributes or return a new instance filled with those attributes
$findItorNot = Category::firstOrNew($attributes);
```